# Проверка логина с помощью regExp

Tags: регулярные-выражения, javascript

Приветствую. Прошу помощи в составлении регулярки для проверки логина.
Логин должен содержать от 4 до 10 символов и может состоять из цифр и букв латинского алфавита и содержать знак подчёркивания и/или дефиса.

Вот мок код, но он, как вы уже догадались, не работает.

```
if(/[^0-9a-zA-Z\-\_]{4,10}$/g.test(str))
    res.innerHTML = 'good';
  else
    res.innerHTML = 'bad';
```

Comment: ^ должна быть перед квадратными скобками, в остальном хз, но ограничивать подобными рамками пользователей - прошлый век

Comment: > /^[\w_]{4,10}$/ig  
Так должно получится.

Comment: Хмм.. а что вы тогда предлагаете? Разрешить любые символы?

Comment: разрешить кирилицу, а возможно даже 駅屋音花歌夏家, мало ли

Comment: @ReinRaus, в \\w входит _, но не входит -, поэтому:

`/^[\w-]{4,10}$/i`

Comment: @LightShock, а что, собственно, вас смущает в том, чтобы дать  свободу выбора логина таким, каким пользователь его хотел бы видеть? Ваше дело экранировать не желательные символы, переводить некоторые из них в сущьности, поставить ограничение на минимальное кол-во знаков и др.

Comment: @deonis, согласен, знаки попутал.

Comment: > @deonis, согласен, знаки попутал.

@ReinRaus, явно меня перепутали с @shurik-ом )))

Comment: @Spectre, ну думаю разрешить иероглифы это точно лишнее.

@Deonis, согласен, но не полностью.. Если разрешить и латиницу и кириллицу, то это даст возможность создавать визуальные клоны других ников, что будет путать других пользователей. Например, написание "Deonis" и "Dеоnis". С виду одно и тоже слово, но пользователь-то разный.

Comment: Стандартная практика это логин из латиницы и цифр и ник из любых символов. Для устранения визуальных клонов ников можно другое регулярное выражение написать.

Comment: Как вариант, можно разрешить использовать либо только латинский алфавит, либо только кириллицу.
Пытаюсь сделать регулярку для кириллицы, но всё тщетно.. Подскажите, что тут исправить нужно?
    /^[а-я0-9-]{4,10}$/i.test(str)

Comment: по-моему современный тренд - это регистрация через социальные сети или использование емейла как логин

Comment: В простейшем случае.  

    /^(?:[-\w]{4,10}|[-а-я0-9_]{4,10})$/i

Comment: @ReinRaus, а сейчас практически любые символы пропускает..

Answer (score 3):

В принципе как и написал ReinRaus

```
 if(/^[\w-]{4,10}$/i.test(str))
        res.innerHTML = 'good';
      else
        res.innerHTML = 'bad';
```